# Optimizing an averaged perceptron algorithm using numpy and scipy instead of dictionaries

Tags: optimization, numpy, implementation, perceptron, scipy

So I'm trying to write an averaged perceptron algorithm [(page 48 here for the equation)](http://ciml.info/dl/v0_8/ciml-v0_8-ch03.pdf) in python. Instead of storing the historical weights, I simply accumulate the weights and then multiply consistency counter, $c$, that is the variable `w_accum`.

My implementation initially had the weight vectors and x represented as dictionaries where a feature is in the dictionary only if it's active, that was supposed to be the most efficient way I could think of. Here is that code:

```
def train():
    #Initialize w, bias
    self.w, self.w['bias'] = {feature:0.0 for feature in features}, 0.0
    self.w_accum, self.w_accum['bias'] = {feature:0.0 for feature in features}, 0.0
    c = 0
    # Iterate over the training data n times
    for i in range(iterations):
        # Check each training example
        for i in range(len(x_train)):
            xi, yi = x_train[i], y_train[i]
            y_hat = self.predict(xi)
            #Update weights if there is a misclassification
            if yi != y_hat:
                ## self.w_accum += self.w*c (basically that's what I'm doing)
                self.w_accum = {feature:self.w_accum[feature]+c*self.w[feature] for feature in self.w_accum}
                c = 1
                for feature, value in xi.items():
                    self.w[feature] = self.w[feature] + yi*eta*value
                self.w['bias'] = self.w['bias'] + yi*eta
            else:
                c += 1
```

with `predict(self, x)` being defined as follows:

```
def predict(self, x):
    if (x.shape[1] == (self.w.shape[0]-1)): # Bias
       x = hstack([x, np.ones(1)])
    s = np.dot(x.toarray(),self.w)
    return 1 if s > 0 else -1
```

The problem with this implementation is that it got `SIGKILL`'ed on massive data sets, and I had to come up with a different solution, so I turned to scipy's sparse.DictVectorizer and ran it over the dictionaries to turn them into sparse dictionaries to use. Now my w and x are represented as `csr_matrix` objects. Here is what the new updated code looks like:

```
 def train(x_train, y_train):
        #Initialize w, bias
        len_features = x_train[0].shape[1]
        self.w = np.zeros((len_features+1,1))
        self.w_accum = np.zeros((len_features+1,1))
        c = 0
        # Iterate over the training data n times
        for i in range(epochs):
            # Check each training example
            for i in range(x_train.shape[0]):
                xi, yi = x_train[i], y_train[i]
                xi = hstack([xi, np.ones(1)])
                y_hat = self.predict(xi)
                #Update weights if there is a misclassification
                if yi != y_hat:
                    self.w_accum += self.w*c
                    c = 1
                    self.w += xi.transpose()*eta*yi
                elif yi == y_hat:
                    c += 1
```

and the `predict` function is as follows:

```
def predict(self, x):
    if (x.shape[1] == (self.w.shape[0]-1)): # X_{n+1} = 1
       x = hstack([x, np.ones(1)])
    s = np.dot(x.toarray(),self.w)
    return 1 if s > 0 else -1
```

The problem is that this code is actually *SLOWER* than my previous implementation! I have no idea why. The code **seems** to take a long time around the `x.transpose()` command (third to last line in `train`) and in the `np.dot` call.

I thought using a sparse dictionary was supposed to be the solution? Is it because I'm using a dot product over all the features, even the zeros? Is there a way to fix this? I thought sparse vectors were optimal for these sorts of things?